# get Form1_MouseMove() event on module from Form vb6

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

how to get the event `Form1_MouseMove` from module, i tried the following in my module but don't works.

```
Public sub Form1_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)

'CODE'

End Sub
```

Comment: That procedure must be inside the form, just call your function in a module from within it.

Answer (score 1):

In *Form1*

```
Private Sub Form_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As  Single, Y As Single)
    Module1.Form1_MouseMove Button, Shift, X, Y
end sub
```

In *Module1*

```
Public Sub Form1_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    'CODE'
End Sub
```